# Counting null rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I trying to find out how many rows and columns in a matrix have all elements equal to zero. I don't know if my solution is the most elegant one so I'd like to know you opinion.

What I did was use two lists that register which are the non null rows and columns and at the end I print the total number of rows and columns minus those on the lists.

What's bothering me the most is the if statements I had to use.

```
def apenas_zeros(matriz):
    linha = len(matriz)
    coluna = len(matriz[0])

    linha_cheia = []
    coluna_cheia = []
    for i in range(linha):
        for k in range(coluna):
            if matriz[i][k] != 0:
                if i not in linha_cheia and k not in coluna_cheia:
                    linha_cheia.append(i)
                    coluna_cheia.append(k)
                elif k not in coluna_cheia:
                    coluna_cheia.append(k)
                elif i not in linha_cheia:
                    linha_cheia.append(i)
    print ("Linhas nulas:", linha - len(linha_cheia))
    print ("Colunas nulas:", coluna - len(coluna_cheia))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `matriz` is a `numpy` array, you could simply do

```
print("Linhas nulas:", sum(~matriz.any(axis=1)))
print("Colunas nulas:", sum(~matriz.any(axis=0)))
```

(your code yields the same result)

Explanation:
`any` is `True` if any element in the given axis is non-zero. `~` just negates this value, i.e. it's `True` if all elements are zero. `True` is 1 and `False` is 0, so counting the `True`s is just doing the sum.

If your `matriz` is a list of lists you can convert it to a numpy array by:

```
import numpy as np
matriz = np.array(matriz)
```

---

Numpy also has a built-in function [`count_nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) for counting non-zeros. Using it comes close to your algorithm:

```
print("Linhas nulas:", matriz.shape[0] - np.count_nonzero(np.count_nonzero(matriz, axis=1)))
print("Colunas nulas:", matriz.shape[1] - np.count_nonzero(np.count_nonzero(matriz, axis=0)))
```